# How to model a Globe of Invisibility power

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, mutants-and-masterminds

I'm designing a Mutants and Masterminds (3rd edition) character that has the following power.

> Dave is a pretty ordinary guy, but he's seldom noticed. He's constantly surrounded by a Globe of Invisibility. Creatures inside the globe are completely undetectable to any machines and to creatures outside the globe. Dave has some control over the globe. He can control the size of the globe, but it is always a sphere and it is never smaller than himself.

The following example demonstrates Dave's powers.

> Dave and Lucile open the front doors to the chocolatier's factory and step inside. The security supervisor watching the monitors in the back room sees the front door swing open and shut as if disturbed by the wind. As they approach the front security desk, Dave expands his globe of invisibility to envelope the two guards at the front desk. Lucile announces in a loud voice, "Excuse me ..." The guards look up in surprise, "Sorry we didn't notice you come in." In the back room, the supervisor notices that the front desk is vacant. Her voice crackles over the radio, "Squad 241, why aren't you at your post"? One of the guards replies into his radio, "We are at the main desk, sir. If there's been a rotation we haven't been relieved." Lucile's hands explode in a violent flash of neon, bathing the entire entryway in light. The supervisor gazes at the wall of monitors wondering why the foyer is still empty and why squad 241 didn't report in.

How can we complete the following description of Dave's power?

> **Globe of Invisibility**: [Concealment](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/concealment-sensory) (total concealment from *all* [sense](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/senses-sensory) types other than tactile) 10 ranks (2 points per rank), [Attack](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-ATTACK-0-COST-PER-RANK-), [Precise](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-PRECISE-FLAT-1-POINT-) (Flat +1 point), [Area](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-AREA-1-COST-PER-RANK-) (Burst 120 ft) (+3 per rank), [Limited](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-LIMITED--1-COST-PER-RANK-) (only affects creatures, doesn't work against affected creatures) (-1 per rank) * *41 points*
>
> **Dave's not Here**: Concealment (total concealment from *all* sense types other than tactile) 10 ranks (2 points per rank), [Permanent](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-PERMANENT--1-COST-PER-RANK-) (-1 per rank), [Quirk](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-QUIRK-FLAT--1-POINT-PER-RANK-) (doesn't work against creatures affected by **Globe of Invisibility**) (Flat -1 point) * *9 points*

Precise (Flat +1 point) seems like enough to buy the ability to change the radius of the sphere. The other possibility would be [Selective](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-SELECTIVE-1-COST-PER-RANK-) (+1 per rank) and a Quirk (Flat -x points) that only the radius can be adjusted.

The limitation that **Globe of Invisibility** only affects creatures would be enough to warrant Limited by itself. Is the additional limitation that it doesn't work against affected creatures enough to warrant another application of Limited?

Does the **Globe of Invisibility** need [Subtle](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers#TOC-SUBTLE-FLAT-1-POINTS-PER-RANK-) (Flat +2 points) so that the globe itself won't be noticed?

The Attack modifier says that the **Globe of Invisibility** only "affects one creature of any size" and that "the target gets a resistance check, determined when the effect is made into an attack... A successful check negates the effect." The Area modifier adds that "No attack check is needed... Potential targets in the area are permitted a Dodge resistance check (DC 10 + effect rank) to avoid some of the effect. A successful resistance check reduces the Area effect to half its normal rank against that target (round down, minimum rank 1)."

How can Dave's power affect everything within the globe without granting them a resistance check? Are creatures granted two resistance checks (one from Attack and one from Area), or only granted the one from Area?

Comment: Important question: Does the limitation that the power only affects creatures mean that Dave's clothing is unaffected?

Comment: @GMJoe No. All of the creatures' gear and powers and weapons they are throwing around are invisible outside of the bubble (until they exit the bubble).

Comment: Hmmmmmmmm... Does Shapeable Area let you do an area smaller than its rank? If so, you could use that and Limit it to only being a sphere (or maybe a Quirk, depends on your GM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your GM allows use of the Power Profiles, I'd recommend asking whether you can use the modified Obscure effect. Rather than "inflict" Concealment as something that can be saved against, it goes back to the 2E model where the concealment is simply something which is there. Define your Obscure as dealing with all five available sense types and you're clear except for allowing those within the effect to see through it. I would personally allow that as a 1 PP Flat Extra, but otherwise, it could be built as a Linked Area Affects Others Senses (Counters Concealment [Globe of Invisibility descriptor]).

> Obscure is a sensory effect requiring a standard action, ranged, and sustained. Cost is based on the senses affected, similar to Illusion: A single sense for 1 point per rank, two senses for 2 points per rank, and so forth, with visual senses costing double (2 points per rank) and 5 points per rank affecting all sense types.
>
> Obscure affects a default area with a 30 foot radius (distance rank 0). Each additional rank increases the distance rank of the area by 1. So Obscure 10 has a radius of 2 miles, while Obscure 20 has a radius of 2,000 miles!